# Getting asynchronous Twitter Profile image iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter, objective-c-blocks

Can't work out why the profileImage is not sticking... (I added the pImage just to see if it was to do with being inside a block... it's not).

profileImage is just a normal syntheized property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *profileImage;

-(void)fetchProfileImage
{
    __block UIImage *pImage;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
    {
        NSString *url_ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/%@", userName];

        TWRequest *fetchUserImageRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

        [fetchUserImageRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
         {
             if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) 
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"[UIImage imageWithData:responseData] = %@", [UIImage imageWithData:responseData]);

                    pImage = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];

                    NSLog(@"pImage = %@", pImage);

                    self.profileImage.image = pImage;

                    NSLog(@"self.profileImage.image = %@", self.profileImage.image);

                });
             }
         }];
    });
}
```

The Log:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:responseData] = <UIImage: 0x2685d0>
pImage = <UIImage: 0x2685d0>
self.profileImage.image = (null)
```

Comment: we can't see the attributes of self.profileImage. I'm guessing this is the problem. Also you don't need pImage to be defined outside the loop. Another question, does "self" exist when the response returns?

Comment: @PauldeLange How'd you mean can't see the attributes? self returns correctly.

Comment: is profileImage valid? Perhaps it has been set to nil somewhere else? If either self or profileImage is nil, this will happen. I presume profileImage is a UIImageView, is your view loaded?

Comment: dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0) can be replaced with dispatch_get_main_queue() just to make sure you are on the UI thread also.

Comment: In fact, something is fishy here. There should be no reason to create the TWRequest object in a different thread to the calling function.

Comment: The code block is copied from Apples example and works in a different part of the app.

Comment: But I will definitely try the other dispatch method, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't initialised the UIImageView when creating the parent object

```
tweet.profileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```